# Catch signals SIGUSR1 or SIGTERM with signalfd on MPI applications?

Tags: mpi

A simple MPI code to catch the SIGUSR1, SIGTERM signals with signalfd unix system call

```
        #include <assert.h>        
        #include <poll.h>      
        #include <signal.h>         
        #include <stdio.h>      
        #include <sys/signalfd.h>      
        #include <unistd.h>    
        #include <mpi.h>    
        /*Simple MPI Code*/
        int main(int argc, char* argv[]){    
            MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);    
            int err, nbProcs, rank;    
            sigset_t sigset;    
            int fd;    
            MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nbProcs);    
            MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank); 

           ****
           Setup SIGALRM to be delivered via SignalFD
           ****   
            sigset_t mask;    
            sigemptyset(&mask);      
            sigaddset(&mask, SIGTERM);       
            sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR1);      
            /* */       
            if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL) < 0) {     
                printf("Failed to signalmask\n");     
                return -1;          
            }          
            fd = signalfd(-1, &mask, 0);     
            if (fd < 0)      
                return -1;      
            while (1) {      
                struct signalfd_siginfo si;     
                int ret;     
                ret = read(fd, &si, sizeof(si));// here the MPI process doesn't 
                                                return when I send SIGTERM or SIGUSR1      
                if (ret < 0)     
                    return -1;      
                if (ret != sizeof(si))        
                    return -1;      
                if (si.ssi_signo == SIGTERM)      
                    printf("receive SIGTERM \\\n");       
                else if (si.ssi_signo == SIGUSR1)        
                    printf("receive SIGUSR1\n");      
            }           
            MPI_Finalize();      
            return 0;  
    }
```

In this code, I am using signalfd to catch SIGUSR1, SIGTERM. At

> ret = read(fd, &si, sizeof(si));

read() system call it doesn't return and the program dies at this point. When I use the same code without MPI simple C code it works perfect.Can anyone explain me how does signalfd works inside MPI???

Comment: How do you run your program? How do you send the signal to your program?

Comment: I run with  **mpirun -np 1 ./mpitest**  and from another linux console i send
  **kill -s SIGUSR1 (pidof mpirun or  pidof mpitest)**

Comment: If you `kill mpirun`, then you implicitly expects `mpirun` will catch and propagate the signal to all the MPI tasks, and your MPI library might not do that.

Comment: I have done another runs killing only mpitest **kill -s SIGUSR1 (pidof mpitest)** without killing **mpirun**  but it's the same thing the mpi application is closed immediately without catching the signal.

Comment: the root cause is an interaction with pthreads I do not understand.
You can reproduce the issue without MPI by creating a dummy thread at the very beginning of your program. A workaround is to `sigprocmask(...)` **before** invoking `MPI_Init()`.